# How can i Bulk Change Category Page Title, Meta Description/Keywords

Tags: magento-1.9, category, seo, update-handle

I need to Change SEO keywords for categories. How can i **Bulk Change Category Page Title, Meta Description/Keywords**.

Answer (score 0):

i have custom script (not tested)

```
<?php
ini_set("memory_limit","-1");
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); 
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
//************************ Import CSV File ************************
// Sample CSV Format
//category_id   meta_title      meta_description    meta_keywords
//1986          Test 123        test            test, test123           
//1904          Test 123        test            test, test123       

$file='category.csv';// Name of CSV file

$rows = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file));
$header = array_shift($rows);
$category_ids=array();
$csv=array(); //csv array with key as Category Id
$a=array();
$i=0;
foreach ($rows as $row) { 

    $csv[] = array_combine($header, $row);
}

/*
************************ Array Format ************************
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($csv);

Array
(
    [1986] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 1986
            [meta_title] => Test 123
            [meta_description] => test
            [meta_keywords] => test, test123
        )

    [1904] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 1904
            [meta_title] => Test 123
            [meta_description] => test
            [meta_keywords] => test, test123
        )

)*/

$category_ids=array_keys($csv); // All the Category Id which we want to update

//************************ Load Categories which we want to Update ************************
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$tree = $category->getTreeModel();
$tree->load();
$categories = $tree->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$category_ids));

$count=0; //Count
foreach($categories as $category)
{
    echo $id=$category->getId().'   -   <a href="'.str_replace('seoupdate','index',$category->getUrl()).'">'.$category->getName().'</a><br>'; // Print name of categories ;just for our info

    if($csv[$id]['meta_title'] != '')
        $category->setMetaTitle($csv[$id]['meta_title']);

    if($csv[$id]['meta_description'] != '')
        $category->setMetaDescription($csv[$id]['meta_description']);

    if($csv[$id]['meta_keywords'] != '')
        $category->setMetaKeywords($csv[$id]['meta_keywords']);

    $category->save();
    $count++;
}

echo $count.' Categories Updated';
```

Comment: Looks great, would be nice if we could export it first too

Comment: Add loop above this and use get instead of set

Answer (score 0):

Unlike products by default there's no import/export for categories in Magento. Mage Works created categories import/export functionality on demand for their customer and later on made it available to public [Extension Link](http://www.magentoworks.net/importexport-magento-category-extension/)

You can export your categories in csv file, make changes and upload it back up. I assume it let's you update meta data but you can make sure it does all what you require before installing it.